# Ajax request a devolver erro 403 Forbidden?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Eu tenho o seguinte código no meu site.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var id = $("#id_radio").val();
    var id_glob;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/update_radio.php",
        data: "id="+id,
        success:function(e){
            $("#nome_radio").removeClass("ellipsis");
            $("#hora_radio").removeClass("ellipsis");
            if(e!==""){
                var expl = e.split(",");
                var id_glob = expl[3];
                if(expl[3] !== id){
                $("#img_radio").animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#img_radio").attr("src", "radio/programas/"+expl[3]+"/"+expl[0]);
                    $("#img_radio").css("width", "100%");
                }, 300)
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#img_radio").animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 300);
                }, 300)
                $("#nome_radio").html(expl[1]);
                $(".programa_radio").html(expl[1]);
                $(".horario_radio").html(expl[2]);
                $("#hora_radio").html(expl[2]);
                $("#id_radio").val(expl[3]);
                $("#pub_radio").animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#pub_radio").attr("src", "adm/images/publicidades/"+expl[5]+"/"+expl[6]);
                    $("#pub_radio").css("max-width", "100%");
                }, 300)
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#pub_radio").animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 300);
                }, 300)
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax/update_pub_radio.php",
                        data: "id="+$("#id_radio").val(),
                        success: function(t){
                             $(".carousel_imgs").animate({
                                opacity: 0
                            }, 300);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $(".carousel_imgs").html(t);
                            }, 300)
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $(".carousel_imgs").animate({
                                    opacity: 1
                                }, 300);
                            }, 300)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    });

}, 1000);
```

Com este código ele a cada segundo atualiza o programa atual da rádio mas passado um pouco começa a aparecer um erro na consola (403 Forbidden). Eu tenho o exato mesmo código noutro website e funciona perfeitamente.

E além de dar erro 403 na consola, o site todo fica forbidden 403 até passados alguns segundos.

Tenho algo de errado?

Comment: Olha com o tipo `POST` você está tentando enviar uma variável tipo `GET`, `"id="+id`. Se você pretende enviar via post tente enviar assim: `data: { id: id }`, não esqueça do `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com o código *JavaScript*. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Mas o pedido é feito através desse código por isso deve haver algo que possa fazer.

Comment: @I_like_trains Já tentou simular as requisições com o [**cURL**](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) ou [**Postman**](https://www.getpostman.com/) e averiguar o resultado?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Não, poderá criar um exemplo de como o fazer?

Comment: Fiz um `.sh` bem básico (e não testei) https://hastebin.com/jihalutuha.bash

Comment: Você está mandando uma requisição a cada segundo para o servidor, mesmo se você não receber a resposta você manda outro logo em seguida. Talvez seja melhor mudar a forma como você atualiza os dados. O Que pode acontecer é você estar enchendo o servidor de requisições e depois de um tempo ele "trava". Acredite, mesmo sendo dados leves tem servidor que não vale nada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É como disse a [resposta do @Henrique Pauli](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304679/8063), mas eu acho que se pode ir mais a fundo no problema e ainda fazer algumas observações no código.

**O problema do setInterval:**

O `setInterval` **nunca** deve ser usado para fazer requisições Ajax em intervalos de tempo. Como sugere a resposta supra citada, o `setInteval` não tem nenhuma sincronia com o Ajax, ou seja, o Ajax depende do retorno da requisição, enquanto o temporizador `setInterval` ficará sendo processado a cada intervalo informado (no seu caso, 1 segundo) disparando o Ajax uma vez atrás da outra em um intervalo muito curto, sem esperar ou querer saber se a requisição anterior foi completada. O resultado disso é sobrecarga do servidor e do navegador, causando travamentos no navegador, pois irá criar um gargalo para muitas informações na fila de processamento, um comportamento bem parecido à um loop infinito, que trava completamente o sistema.

Em vista disso, possivelmente o erro 403 se dá pelo excesso de requisições em curtos intervalos de tempo e/ou pela sobrecarga do servidor. Com isso, como forma de se defender contra abusos, o servidor pode estar suspendendo o acesso temporariamente, daí o erro 403.

**Intervalo de 1 segundo**

Mesmo com as correções, acredito que 1 segundo é um intervalo ainda muito curto para enviar requisições seguidas, mas se o servidor aguenta esse volume, então tudo bem.

**Redundância no código**

Noto também algumas redundâncias no código que poderia deixar seu código um pouco mais leve:

1) **4 setTimeout**s com o mesmo tempo no primeiro Ajax e 2 no segundo. Ex.:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".carousel_imgs").html(t);
}, 300)
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".carousel_imgs").animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 300);
}, 300)
```

Quando poderia ser 1 `setTimeout` apenas:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".carousel_imgs")
   .html(t)
   .animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 300);
}, 300)
```

2) Alterações idênticas de forma separada. Ex.:

```
$("#nome_radio").removeClass("ellipsis");
$("#hora_radio").removeClass("ellipsis");
```

Quando poderia reduzir desta forma abaixo, já que ambos os elementos irão perder a classe `.ellipsis` ao mesmo tempo:

```
$("#nome_radio, #hora_radio").removeClass("ellipsis");
```

**Chamando novamente a função `raDio()` após o Ajax:**

Como você está usando dois Ajax aninhados, a lógica seria:

Se o primeiro Ajax *der certo* (`success`), chamar o segundo. Mas se ele *der errado* (`error`), chamar novamente a função após 1 segundo.

Se o primeiro *deu certo* (`success`), irá chamar o segundo, mas no segundo você deveria usar o callback `complete` para iniciar tudo de novo após 1 segundo. Por que no `complete`? Porque independentemente se deu erro ou não nesse segundo Ajax, você irá querer iniciar a função novamente. O `complete` é chamado sempre, se deu erro ou não.

Em todos os casos, como sugeriu a outra resposta, você irá usar o `setTimeout` nesses callbacks.

**Explicações terminadas, veja como ficaria o código organizado:**

```
function raDio(){
   var id = $("#id_radio").val();
   var id_glob;
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/update_radio.php",
      data: "id="+id,
      success:function(e){
         $("#nome_radio, #hora_radio").removeClass("ellipsis");
         if(e!==""){
            var expl = e.split(",");
            var id_glob = expl[3];
            if(expl[3] !== id){
               $("#img_radio").animate({
                  opacity: 0
               }, 300);

               setTimeout(function(){
                  $("#img_radio")
                  .attr("src", "radio/programas/"+expl[3]+"/"+expl[0])
                  .css("width", "100%")
                  .animate({
                     opacity: 1
                  }, 300);

                  $("#pub_radio")
                  .attr("src", "adm/images/publicidades/"+expl[5]+"/"+expl[6])
                  .css("max-width", "100%")
                  .animate({
                     opacity: 1
                  }, 300);
               }, 300)

               $("#nome_radio, .programa_radio").html(expl[1]);
               $(".horario_radio, #hora_radio").html(expl[2]);
               $("#id_radio").val(expl[3]);
               $("#pub_radio").animate({
                  opacity: 0
               }, 300);

               $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "ajax/update_pub_radio.php",
                  data: "id="+$("#id_radio").val(),
                  success: function(t){
                     $(".carousel_imgs").animate({
                        opacity: 0
                     }, 300);
                     setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".carousel_imgs")
                        .html(t)
                        .animate({
                           opacity: 1
                        }, 300);
                     }, 300);
                  },
                  complete: function(){
                     setTimeout(raDio, 1000); // chama a função
                  }
               });
            }
         }
      },
      error: function(){
         setTimeout(raDio, 1000); // chama a função se deu erro
      }
   });
}

$(document).ready(raDio); // chama a função após o carregamento do DOM
```

Comment: Perfeito! Usei o seu código e funcionou mas no entanto outro problema apareceu mas que consegui resolver. O site onde estou a trabalhar foi feito por outro programador e está todo com `mysql` enquanto que o código da página do `ajax` estava todo em `mysqli`

Comment: Mas agora que dei conta, não aconteceu bem o que eu queria, pois o objetivo era ele ver a hora atual e comparar com as horas dos programas na base de dados e ver qual deles estava dentro do horário. Com esse código ele só vê quando a página carrega

Comment: Usei um setInterval mas desta vez pus para atualizar a cada 5 segundos e funciona lindamente. Pelo que parece o servidor não permitia tantas requisições

Answer (score 2):

Como eu disse no meu comentário creio que o problema seja você estar mandando requisições demais para o servidor. Imagine o seguinte:

A cada segundo você manda 1 requisição, se uma delas demorar mais de 1 segundo para responder você vai mandar mais uma em cima dela. Logo você tem uma cascata esperando resposta e trava tudo.

O que você pode fazer para tentar amenizar isso é mandar a requisição 1 segundo DEPOIS que tudo terminou. Algo como:

```
function atualizarRadio() {
    var id = $("#id_radio").val();
    var id_glob;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/update_radio.php",
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function (e) {
            $("#nome_radio").removeClass("ellipsis");
            $("#hora_radio").removeClass("ellipsis");
            if (e !== "") {
                var expl = e.split(",");
                var id_glob = expl[3];
                if (expl[3] !== id) {
                    $("#img_radio").animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 300);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#img_radio").attr("src", "radio/programas/" + expl[3] + "/" + expl[0]);
                        $("#img_radio").css("width", "100%");
                    }, 300)
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#img_radio").animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 300);
                    }, 300)
                    $("#nome_radio").html(expl[1]);
                    $(".programa_radio").html(expl[1]);
                    $(".horario_radio").html(expl[2]);
                    $("#hora_radio").html(expl[2]);
                    $("#id_radio").val(expl[3]);
                    $("#pub_radio").animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 300);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#pub_radio").attr("src", "adm/images/publicidades/" + expl[5] + "/" + expl[6]);
                        $("#pub_radio").css("max-width", "100%");
                    }, 300)
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#pub_radio").animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 300);
                    }, 300)
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax/update_pub_radio.php",
                        data: "id=" + $("#id_radio").val(),
                        success: function (t) {
                            $(".carousel_imgs").animate({
                                opacity: 0
                            }, 300);
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(".carousel_imgs").html(t);
                            }, 300)
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(".carousel_imgs").animate({
                                    opacity: 1
                                }, 300);
                            }, 300)
                            setTimeout(atualizarRadio,1000); // Terminou tudo, reiniciar.
                        }
                    })
                }else setTimeout(atualizarRadio,1000); // Não chegou ao fim mas precisa reiniciar.
            }else setTimeout(atualizarRadio,1000); // Não chegou ao fim mas precisa reiniciar.
        }
    });
}
atualizarRadio();
```

OBS: Editei um pouco o seu código para não usar interval e se tornar uma função. Não tenho acesso aos seus dados então só você poderá testar. Espero que ajude pelo menos para dar uma luz ao seu problema.